# How to create mapping between DOM Element and Angular

Tags: angular

I want to create a mapping between components which are created from angular and the resulting dom elements.

Here is the story why I think I need that: My aim is to create a masonry like 2-column layout. Because I want to order the tiles in a specific manner (based on its height) I need to get the DOM-Element height first before ordering the tiles.
First I wanted to calculate a number based on the information which each tile has but this solution doesn't hold up when the CSS changes because of dynamic fields in each tile).

So my first step is to query the height of each element (one time on the parent component by using:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElements.querySelectorAll('.hero-card');
```

From there I get a NodeList with DIV HTML-Elements. My problem is now mapping those elements back to the component which created them. I could introduce an ID but I do not know how I can add it to the DOM Attributes

Here is an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzx335

Comment: what do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chellappan said in his comments, it is a little hard to understand what you are trying to do. I think the following will get you what you want though:

Add `ViewChildren` to your imports from `'@angular/core'`.

Add another property to your AppComponent:
`@ViewChildren(HeroDetailComponent) details;`

Update the `ngAfterViewInit` method to

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const domElements: NodeList = this.results.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.hero-card');
    console.log(domElements);
    console.log(this.details);
    console.log(this.details.first.el.nativeElement)
  }
```

Is the last `console.log` what you are trying to get?

Comment: I think I looked for ViewChildren, with that I can have one item with multiple Components (QueryList). Thanks for the advise.